# UPDATE table with two different values

Tags: sql, oracle

Have this table:  TEST

```
//TEST
A#                  STATUS
----------------------------
 1
 2
 3
```

Another table name : TEST1

```
//TEST1
A#
----------
 1 
 2
```

Used following query:

```
Update TEST t set t.Status='y' WHERE 
EXISTS (SELECT t1.A# FROM TEST1 t1);
```

But i want to set the status if found the record then insert 'Y' Else 'X'
The expected output is like this:

```
    A#                  STATUS
--------------------------------
     1                     Y
     2                     Y
     3                     X
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement:

```
Update TEST t
set    t.Status = ( case
                    when EXISTS (SELECT t1.A# FROM TEST1 t1)
                    then 'y'
                    else 'x'
                    end
                  )
```